# ADF - Odata - How to perform an optional select

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory

I've created an ADF flow that loops over URL's to fetch OData using the OData connection.

However, not all fields are available in all URL's, there are certain ones that are available in one URL, but not in the other. A $Select is used to select the fields that we need.

Is it possible to have an optional selection (as in, if the path is not available, do not fetch this field and return null instead for instance)? Would help us a great deal.

I've tried adding ? after the field, but that does not work. `$select=Field1,Field2,FieldOptional?`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to loop through a bunch of a URL and the query on the ODATA URL will change and so will be the fields . I think you can use a lookup where you pass the unique url and its gives the fields and then concatenate the url with the fields and make a odata call .